# Display Text and Image from local folder on webview

Tags: c#, json, database, webview, uwp

I have a database and webview. I want webview to be able to display text and images in the local folder.

Database:
[image: database]

The database is obtained from JSON below:

```
"list_soal": [
            {
                "qid": "33840",
                "question": "<p><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/16.JPG\" />Lafal&nbsp;yang melengkapi ayat tersebut adalah &hellip;.</p>",
                "has_img": "1",
                "images": [
                    "https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/16.JPG"
                ],
                "jawaban": [
                    {
                        "oid": "81912",
                        "q_option": "<p><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1a1.JPG\" /></p>",
                        "score": "0",
                        "has_img": "1",
                        "images": [
                            "https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1a1.JPG"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "oid": "81913",
                        "q_option": "<p><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1b1.JPG\" /></p>",
                        "score": "1",
                        "has_img": "1",
                        "images": [
                            "https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1b1.JPG"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "oid": "81914",
                        "q_option": "<p><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1c1.JPG\" /></p>",
                        "score": "0",
                        "has_img": "1",
                        "images": [
                            "https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1c1.JPG"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "oid": "81915",
                        "q_option": "<p><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1d1.JPG\" /></p>",
                        "score": "0",
                        "has_img": "1",
                        "images": [
                            "https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/1d1.JPG"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

For img scr, I change it to the image path in the local folder.

Code:

```
StorageFolder installedLocation = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;    
StorageFolder library = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("library", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                                            StorageFolder gambar = await library.CreateFolderAsync("gambar", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                                            StorageFolder imgName = await gambar.CreateFolderAsync(quizID.ToString(), CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                                            string imgPath = imgName.Path;
                                            string soal = "";
                                            if(question.Pertanyaan.ToString().Contains("https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/"))
                                            {   
                                                soal = Regex.Replace(question.Pertanyaan, "\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/", "''file:\\" + "\\" + "\\" + imgPath + "\\");
                                                soal = Regex.Replace(soal, ".JPG\"", ".jpg''");
                                            }
                                            string InsertQuestion = @"INSERT INTO DBQuestion (QID,Pertanyaan, QuizID) SELECT '" + question.QID.ToString() + "','" + soal + "','" + quiz.ID + "' WHERE not exists " +
                                            "(select QID and Pertanyaan and QuizID FROM DBQuestion WHERE QID='" + question.QID.ToString() + "' and Pertanyaan='" + soal + "' and QuizID='" + quiz.ID + "')";
                                            var quizQuestion = objConn.Prepare(InsertQuestion);
                                            quizQuestion.Step();
                                        }
    string QuestionPhrase = @"SELECT * FROM DBQuestion WHERE QuizID='" + quizID + "'";
                question = objConn.Prepare(QuestionPhrase);
     question.Step();

                questionText.NavigateToString(question[1].ToString());
```

I'm having a problem, i.e. the images in the local folder can't be displayed on the webview, like the image below:
[image]

How to handle it?

Note:

- The image has been downloaded and saved successfully in the local folder (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\\LocalState\library\gambar\503)
- questionText is the name of webview

Answer (score 0):

UWP applications are sandboxed applications that are isolated from the external environment and cannot access files directly through the path, even WebView.

You can directly pass the http link of the image to the WebView. If you want to access it offline, convert the image to a Base64 string and pass the string as the source of the image.

Here is the convert method:

```cs
public static async Task<string> ImgToBase64(StorageFile file)
{
    var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(GetbytesFromBuffer(buffer));
    result = "data:image/png;base64," + result;
    return result;
}

public static byte[] GetbytesFromBuffer(IBuffer buffer)
{
    DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: In string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes.ToArray()) there is an error message: 'IBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no accessible extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'IBuffer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please make sure your application has a minimum version of 1703 (15063) or higher.

Comment: i set the minimum version is build 16299

Comment: Hi, I update my answer and apply a convert method. I'm not sure if you don't have the `IBuffer.ToArray()` method related to the nuget package version. Can you update the version of the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package?

Comment: I use Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.9 and how to apply it to webview from database?

Comment: From the information you give, the image itself is an http web link, which does not need to be converted to a local link. But if you are reading offline, please convert the downloaded image into a base64 string according to the method I gave before converting to a local link, and set the` src` attribute of `<img>` to the base64 string to display the image.

Comment: I need to display images offline. To insert the image into the database, is it a link path or is it base64?

Comment: I recommend using base64 strings because UWP apps can't access files directly through the path.